# Best way to set attribute of an interface dynamically

Tags: typescript

Given this interface:

```
interface Data {
  name: string;
  route0?: string;
  route1?: string;
  route2?: string;
  route3?: string;
  route4?: string;
  route5?: string;
  route6?: string;
  route7?: string;
  route8?: string;
  route9?: string;
}
```

I want to be able to create objects of this type dynamically from a set of input data. This was my attempt:

```
interface Route {
   ordinal: number;
   value: string;
}

const createData = (name: string, routes: Route[]): Data => {
   const data: Data = { name };

   routes.forEach(route => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-any
      (data as any)[`route${route.ordinal}`] = route.value;
   });

   return data;
};

console.log(createData('dummy', [{ ordinal: 2, value: 'two' }, { ordinal: 7, value: 'seven' }]));
```

Which produces this output:

```
{ name: 'dummy', route2: 'two', route7: 'seven' }
```

The thing I do not like about my solution is that I had to cast **data** to **any** and then tell **tslint** to ignore this cast.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `route0?: string;
  route1?: string;` this doesn't look like a good idea. Why can't you use array instead?

Comment: I've actually tried to present a simplified view of a problem I have. The outer type (Data in this case) is not defined by me and I am forced to use it.

Comment: You could probably cast property name `data[\`route${route.ordinal}\` as keyof Data] = route.value;`. But effectively this is just a way to suppress valid typechecker error. You still can have `ordinal: Math.PI` at runtime ;)

Comment: Nice - at least it is better than casting to any (I think)

Comment: I wonder if anyone can think of a truly type-safe way of doing this?